# Detect Axcrypt files on hard drive

Tags: forensics

I have lost some Axcrypt files on my hard drive, as I have changed the extension.
Is there a way to detect those files (via header, size, etc.)

If not, are there some tools to detect discordance between a file's header and filetype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The encrypted files have a common header. The first 4 bytes of AXX files are `C0 B9 07 2E`. The static header is actually longer than this, but 4 bytes should be enough to rule out false positives.

Comment: Do you know a tool who scan for files with this header ?

Comment: use the command "find" with:
test "$(head -c 4 $file)" = "$(echo -e '\xc0\xb9\x07\x2e')"